# How to set multiple parameters to zero?

Tags: replacement, syntax

Say I have the matrix

```
A = {{a,b,c,d,e}, {f,g,h,j,k}}
```

and I want to set some of these to zero. I have been doing this via

```
A/.{a->0, b->0}.
```

Is there a way to set a bunch to zero at once? I am dealing with many more parameters than 8 and would like to not type "->0," a million times. I tried

```
A/.{a,b,c}->0
```

But this just sets the list {a,b,c} to 0 (I believe). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Look up `ReplacePart[]`. But, you do not have a matrix, since your "rows" do not have the same dimensions.

Comment: Whoops, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In terms of generating the replacement rule efficiently, you can do the following:

```
A = {{a, b, c, d, e}, {f, g, h, j}};    
A /. Thread[{a, b, c} -> 0]

(*{{0, 0, 0, d, e}, {f, g, h, j}}*)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Will put to use immediately!

Comment: Great to hear,  enjoy!

Answer (score 7):

Or you can use `Map`

```
A = {{a, b, c, d, e}, {f, g, h, j}};      
A /. (# -> 0 & /@ {a, b, c})
```

> **Update:**
>   or to have fun.

```
Fold[#1 /. #2 -> 0 &, A, {a, b, c}]
```

Answer (score 4):

I would argue that the most idiomatic solution is

```
A /. a | b | c -> 0
```

Comment: Since he has a long list of parameters that will become zero.. `A /. Alternatives @@ {a, b,c} -> 0`